# Photo Gallery Service for Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-controls, photo-gallery

Hi I need to add photo support for my Application. Searching the site I found reference to nGallery. Any other. I use ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with it?  There are a lot of slideshow/gallery type plugins for jQuery that would work quite nicely in an ASP.NET MVC site.  I'm using the [Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin for a rotating slideshow on one of my sites.  There's also [Galleria](http://www.webappers.com/2008/03/05/galleria-simple-but-nice-jquery-image-gallery/), which looks quite nice.  Google for "[jQuery gallery](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+gallery)" (no offense to see more.

Comment: I have to show photos of a team in the team page. I need something that can show a big photo a a few small ones. Maybe a team can have 30 photos.

Comment: Check out this Cycle demo with paging.  Gives you a thumbnail to click on and loads the full size image in the viewer.  http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager3.html

Comment: Can you have the photo in a Database an create the image from there or you have to save to temp file first?